# Is there any runtime assert like: is the memory readonly or accesible by current process?

Tags: c++, c, kernel, assert

Is there any runtime assert like: is the memory readonly or is memory accesible by current process?
(I am more interest in kernel mode asserts)

Comment: What platform/environment/version etc.?

Comment: @PlasmaHH windows drivers. fs minifilter for instance..

Comment: You get a nice page fault if memory is not accessible or when writing into read-only memory.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: I don't think you get a **nice** page fault from a file system driver. Remember, these are the drivers which are needed to page in a swapped out memory page. If they fault, it's game over.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [but don't use it.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx)

Of course, the idea of "current process" doesn't exist in the kernel. Normally the "current process" is similar to the `this` pointer of an object, it's sort of a hidden variable. Talking about the "current process" in the kernel is like talking about `this` in `main` - it just doesn't exist.

Comment: great link, my idea was: is it possible to check whether memory is accesible, and if not - not hang out system during debug(only) and just return from void.. that will save a lot og time in kernel debugging.  I do not agree that "current process doesn't exist in the kernel" Kernel is the process it has it's own process user process space and that is not the same as "system space" that is available "evryere"

Comment: @BransDs: Feel free to hold on to your opinio. But if you think "kernel address space" is similar to "user address space" you'll find it hard to explain the `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` BSOD you will see.